# how to integrate app action using actions.xml?

Tags: android, action, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I am trying to build a build-in-intent[actions.intent.CHECK_AIR_QUALITY]. I have already added the actions.xml in my project. 
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?><!--  Learn More about how to use 
App Actions: https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/index.html -->
<actions>
    <!--Example Action -->
    <action intentName="actions.intent.CHECK_AIR_QUALITY">
    <action-display
        label="Check quality"
        />
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://www.google.co.in/order{?drop}">
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="drop"
            urlParameter="drop" />
    </fulfillment>
    </action>
</actions>
```

Here I put a sample url in the place of **urlTemplate** . But after I install the app in my device the below option(APP ACTION TEST TOOL) is not coming. Here is the video [link](https://youtu.be/lu3L6DxUBRA?t=1534) where I have taken the screen shot.

[image]

So I do R&D on that and I have found some link for the conversational action of google [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Assistant).

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Do you have get any idea about this requirement from anywhere? If you have any solution drop the comments here

Comment: Still the feature it does not release(https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) it is still progress and about the AS I still have confusion.

Comment: I am also not getting 'App Actions Test Tool' option in Android Studio.
How could i test the google assistant? Please reply if any one have idea about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Google I/O 2019, some updates were posted about App Actions. The menu item you're looking for is enabled by installing the App Actions Test Tool plugin which you can find in the Android Studio plugin marketplace by searching for "App Actions" ([web link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12322-app-actions-test-tool)).

- [Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/app/)
- [Google I/O 2019 session on App Actions (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQALSeGy9aY)
- [Sample application on github](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin)

Comment: Hey I saw your video you just rock.

Comment: Thanks for watching. Feel free to post additional questions about App Actions to stackoverflow (tag: app-actions) and we will do our best to answer them.

Comment: I have a question. I implemented this app: https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin . Changed the package name, but left the rest of the code the same, but when I try "Start running in fit actions" it just gives me google search responses. What am I doing wrong?
Do I need to also put something in my console.actions.google.com?

Comment: @rosualin might be best to post a new question with more details and link to it here, but before trying a query, make sure you test with the Studio Test Tool plugin (https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/quickstart#preview) and ensure that works first, once that's working you can try voice queries.